# Why is std::complex real member function not const?

Tags: c++, stl

Any reason for the member functions "real" and "imag" in the std::complex class not to be const?

Comment: They are `const`; C++14 even makes them `constexpr`.

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the member function versions, not the free versions.

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/real and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/imag

Comment: @chris: But the free functions take a `const complex<T> &`, so how would that cause any confusion here?

Comment: @abarnert, Not paying attention to the parameter list and just looking for a trailing `const` would do it.

Comment: @chris: Well, if you don't look at the parameter list, you don't even know it's a function on `complex` in the first place. (After all, there are overloads for `float`, `double`, etc. too.)

Comment: @abarnert, I was thinking of something like starting [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex), noticing `real`, clicking it (missing the member function link), and looking for the trailing `const` on that page.

Answer (score 2):

There are two overloads for `real` in the `complex` class template:

```
T real() const;
void real(T);
```

The first on *is* `const`, so that can't be what you're asking about.

The second one, which takes a `T` argument and returns nothing, is not `const`, because it's a "setter" method—the whole point of it is to change the state of the object, so it had better not be `const`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at the C++ Standard:

> ## C++ 2011 Section 26.4.2 Class Template Complex
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>     template<class T>
>     class complex {
>         public:
>             typedef T value_type;
>
>             complex(const T& re = T(), const T& im = T());
>             complex(const complex&);
>             template<class X> complex(const complex<X>&);
>
>             T real() const;
>             void real(T);
>             T imag() const;
>             void imag(T);
>
>             complex<T>& operator= (const T&);
>             complex<T>& operator+=(const T&);
>             complex<T>& operator-=(const T&);
>             complex<T>& operator*=(const T&);
>             complex<T>& operator/=(const T&);
>
>             complex& operator=(const complex&);
>             template<class X> complex<T>& operator= (const complex<X>&);
>             template<class X> complex<T>& operator+=(const complex<X>&);
>             template<class X> complex<T>& operator-=(const complex<X>&);
>             template<class X> complex<T>& operator*=(const complex<X>&);
>             template<class X> complex<T>& operator/=(const complex<X>&);
>     };
> }
> ```

I'd say that it's pretty clearly stated that `std::complex::real()` and `std::complex::imag()` are const methods.

Comment: But `std::complex::real(T)` is definitely not a `const` method, and presumably that's what he's asking about. (After all, he didn't specify, or even imply, the overload with no arguments, and he clearly said that it's not `const`.)